# How can i pass many tailwind classes from parent to child in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, tailwind-css

How can I pass classes as props from parent to child, I have a component that is used in many places already and in the place I was told to style it needs to be uppercase, I would like to make it a little more reusable instead of typing multiple conditions I would like to pass them as a prop for parent, however so far I haven't been able to. when I pass it this way

```
<template>
  <div class="font-nunito-semibold">
    <div class="category">
      <underline :text="item.category.label" :tailwind="uppercase"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

and in component I create computed property like so

```
  computed:{
    tailwindClasses() {
      if (this.tailwind) {
        return {...tailwind}
       }
     }
  }
```

and use it like so

```
    <span
      :class="[{
        'o-print': color === 'white',
        'tt-initial': textTransform === 'initial',
      }, 'tailwindClasses']"
      class="text"
      >{{ text }}</span
    >
```

```
<script>
export default {
  props: ["color", "text", "textTransform", "type", "widthStart0", "tailwind"],
  data() {
    return {
      isOver: false,
      widthStartNew: false,
    };
  },
  computed:{
    tailwindClasses() {
      if (this.tailwind) {
        return {...tailwind}
       }
     }
  }
};
</script>
```

In the elements tab it does not compute anything but displays string 'tailwindClasses'

Answer (score 1):

Try using a simple approach like this. Pass the class as an object.

```
  <underline :text="item.category.label" :tailwind="{color:'white'}"/>
```

Then in the child component, you can use something like this:

```
 <span :class="{'o-print': (tailwind.color === 'white')}">
     {{ text }}
 </span>
```